# Unary operator ambiguity

Tags: c, grammar, lexical-analysis, ambiguity, unary-operator

Looking at the C grammar, it seems that the input `++i` can have 2 derivation: either be treated as the prefix increment operator, or as 2 integer promotion, like `+(+i)` (same goes for `--i`).
What am I missing?

```
unary-expression:
   postfix-expression
   ++ unary-expression
   -- unary-expression
   unary-operator cast-expression
   sizeof unary-expression
   sizeof ( type-name )

unary-operator: one of
    & * + - ~ !

cast-expression:
    unary-expression
    ( type-name ) cast-expression
```

Comment: @JonathanLeffler so according to the comments by Robert in this [meta question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266364/why-was-my-question-marked-duplicate-citing-an-existing-similar-answer) these are not duplicates unless it is an exact dup or the dup is a canonical question/answer. Which I found somewhat surprising a position but the meta questions on dups do have somewhat conflicting answers. I have attempted to get a clarification but none so far.

Comment: The basic issue is the maximal munch rule in both cases; they are really about the same issue.  Maybe I should have used [What is the name of this operator: "-->"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642028/what-is-the-name-of-this-operator) instead?  (Mostly joking; that's quite a bit diferent.)  But there are numerous other possible duplicates for this — all boiling down to the maximal munch rule.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler well his argument is that the question has to be a dup just having it boil down to the same answer does not make it a dup. Considering he is moderator I have to take the position seriously.

Comment: Seems like too rigid a position though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The lexer is using the [maximal munch principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximal_munch) and will take as many characters as it can to form a valid token to avoid these types of ambiguity.

We can confirm this by going to the [draft C99 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) section `6.4` *Lexical elements* which says:

> If the input stream has been parsed into preprocessing tokens up to a
>   given character, the next preprocessing token is the longest sequence
>   of characters that could constitute a preprocessing token. [...]

and it provides two examples:

> EXAMPLE 1 The program fragment 1Ex is parsed as a preprocessing number
>   token (one that is not a valid floating or integer constant token),
>   even though a parse as the pair of preprocessing tokens 1 and Ex might
>   produce a valid expression (for example, if Ex were a macro defined as
>   +1). Similarly, the program fragment 1E1 is parsed as a preprocessing number (one that is a valid floating constant token), whether or not E
>   is a macro name.

and

> EXAMPLE 2 The program fragment x+++++y is parsed as x ++ ++ + y, which
>   violates a constraint on increment operators, even though the parse x
>   ++ + ++ y might yield a correct expression.

Answer (score 3):

According to the C Standard

> 4 If the input stream has been parsed into preprocessing tokens up to
>   a given character, the next preprocessing token is the **longest
>   sequence** of characters that could constitute a preprocessing token.

So there is no ambiguity.

For example in this program

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void ) 
{

    int a = 1;
    int b = 10;
    int c = a+++b;

    printf( "c = %d\n", c ); 
}
```

The output will be

```
11
```

because expression

```
a+++b
```

will be interpretated as

```
a++ + b
```

not as

```
a + ++b
```